# Lag after switching from high to low workload

Tags: windows-7, lag

If I run a game on my PC then close it my PC becomes unbelievably laggy. All my drivers are up to date and I have run memtest and that's all fine. I am running an i7 6700k, GTX1070, 16gb of ram and I am on Windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of lag are you getting? What game are you running? Does it eventually go away? What do you do in order to remove the lag?

Comment: My whole PC just runs extremely slowly, doing anything on it is just very laggy, an example game is Player Unknown's Battlegrounds and to get rid of the lag I have to restart my PC